# C# Making it so the Enter Key behaves as if a button has been pressed

Tags: c#, key, enter

How do I code it so that when the enter key has been pressed it behaves as if a button on the existing form has been pressed?

Let's say the button on the form makes it so a display message of hello shows up

```
 private void buttonHello_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
}
```

How do I make it so when the enter key is pressed it does the same thing 
(for the life of me I can't remember and it's probably really simple and I'm being really dumb)

Comment: You should look at the [`KeyUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keyup.aspx)  event

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tell when the enter key is pressed in a TextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806166/how-do-i-tell-when-the-enter-key-is-pressed-in-a-textbox)

Answer (score 27):

WinForms?  If yes, select the FORM.  Now in the Properties Pane (bottom right of the screen by default) change the `AcceptButton` property to "buttonHello".

See [Form.AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx):

> Gets or sets the button on the form that is clicked when the user
> presses the ENTER key.

Here's what it looks like in the Properties Pane:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key down event, like this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter){
        button.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your Form properties, set AcceptButton = yourButton, That's it.

Answer (score 2):

add a [Key Down](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event handler to your form.  Then check if the enter key has been pressed

```
private void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        buttonHello.PerformClick();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for some reason. Is that code to put focus to this command because I have a bunch of other code to be performed.

Comment: form would have to have focus when the enter key is pressed

Comment: did you add the event to the form?

Comment: you need to attach it. `form.KeyDown += form_KeyDown;` in your constructor

Answer (score 1):

For WinForms:

```
using System.Windows.Forms; // reference

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

For WPF:

```
using System.Windows.Input; // reference

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

*Notes*

- This example is for Enter button, you can easy change that changing
  `Keys.YOURKEY`.
- You need to add first the event in your form or window.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:-

```
private void tb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)        
        button.PerformClick();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are driving toward the "Magic Button" antipattern, and the symptom is that you want to drive the butto from somewhere else. Insulate the behavior you want from the button in some way ( a member function could work ) and then call the same function from any point you like.
If you really just want to reply to the enter key, best way is, as suggested by @Idle_mind, use the `AcceptButton`.